# How can I pass a specific variable to each iteration in Ansible loops?

Tags: ansible

For the following task:

```yaml
- name: include my task
  include_tasks: change_state.yaml
  loop:
    - "{{ var1 }}"
    - "{{ var2 }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: switch
```

I want to pass an additional variable for each iteration, like for the first iteration `(var1) --> interface: "{{interface1}}"` and for second iteration `(var2) --> interface: "{{ interface2 }}`"
Is there a way to achieve this in Ansible?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a dict out of your list item:

```yaml
- name: include my task
  include_tasks: change_state.yaml
  loop:
    - var: "{{ var1 }}"
      interface: "{{ interface1 }}"
    - var: "{{ var2 }}"
      interface: "{{ interface2 }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: switch
```

The access in your *change_state.yaml* is then done via `switch.var` and `switch.interface`